# libgdx-android: Intercepting back key and confirm exit

Tags: android, libgdx

Using libgdx, how can I intercept the android BACK key in order to do some preprocessing (e.g. asking for confirmation from user), before actually performing the command to exit the game?

Comment: In case you want to handle it in Screens,
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114972/handling-back-button-in-android-without-implementing-inputprocessor/114985#114985

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**1. Enable catching of Back Key.**

In the class that implements `ApplicationListener`

```
   @Override
   public void create() {
        ...
        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
        ...
   }
```

**2. Handle catching of Back Key.**

In a class that implements the `InputProcessor`

```
   @Override
   public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        ...
        if(keycode == Keys.BACK){
           // Optional back button handling (e.g. ask for confirmation)
           ...
           if (shouldReallyQuit)
             Gdx.app.exit();
        }
        return false;
   }
```

Comment: In case you want to handle it in Screens without input processor,
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114972/handling-back-button-in-android-without-implementing-inputprocessor/114985#114985

Comment: I kept debugging unwanted exit on BACK, until I realized libgdx is so smart that it hijacks the key and must be asked for it.